# AWS Snapshots not saving data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created several snapshots from volumes of my instances months ago. Today I had to restore an instance based on a snapshot, but this instance does not contain any of my data, it is a clean version of Ubuntu, exactly as the first time I created the instance.

How do I restore my data?

thanks

Comment: Was your data stored on one of your EBS volumes, or were you storing data on the ephemeral "instance store" volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS there are two snapshot options:

1- Snapshot: You can use snapshots to capture a point-in-time state of your individual volumes.
2- Amazon Machine Image (AMI): You can use an AMI to capture a point-in-time state of your whole EC2 instance (VM), including all of its volumes.

So, difference is that snapshot is on individual volume level and AMI is the entire instance. Under the hood, AMI takes snapshots of all attached volumes and you can see those snapshots in the corresponding Snapshots page in AWS Management Console.

So to be clear, did you create an AMI from you Ubuntu instance and restored the same AMI? Or did you create a snapshot from one or more of its volumes? In that case, how did you restore it?

If you only take a snapshot of one or more of the volumes, after you restore your snapshots into new volumes attached to an instance, you should also remember to mount those volumes. But if you use an AMI, mounting may not be required, as long as you have added your volumes in the /etc/fstab.